# Mongoose populate with pagination

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, pagination

Trying to implement pagination on my populated query. I'm successful populating with mongoose populate but limit or skip doesn't work. Also tried mongoose-paginate library, pagination work but population not.
As an output I need only array of missions by user id that is paginated. Thank you.

**User schema:**

```
var mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-paginate');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  uavs: [uavSchema],
  missions: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Mission' }],
});

userSchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate);
```

**This works but limit nor skip doesnt work**

```
const getMissions = async (_id) => {
  let missions = [];
  try {
    await User.findOne({ _id: _id })
      .lean()
      .populate('missions')
      .then((usr) => {
        console.log(usr);
        Object.assign(missions, usr.missions);
      });
    return { success: true, missions };
  } catch (err) {
    return { success: false, err };
  }
};
```

[output when using mongoose populate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gj6sX.png)

**Then tried using mongoose-paginate**

```
const getMissions = async (_id) => {
  try {
    var options = {
      populate: 'missions',
      page: 1,
      limit: 4,
      lean: true,
    };
    await User.paginate({ _id: _id }, options, function (err, result) {
      console.log(result);
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

[output when using mongoose-paginate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBwbW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution - searching missions colection**

```
const getMissions = async (_id, page, limit) => {
  try {
    let missions = {};
    var options = {
      page,
      limit,
      lean: true,
    };
    await Mission.paginate({ _owner: _id }, options, function (err, result) {
      Object.assign(missions, result);
    });
    return { success: true, missions };
  } catch (err) {
    return { success: false, err };
  }
};
```